# Set log level for non-ROS nodes (my own nodes)

Tags: ros, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In `rosconsole.config` one can configure ROS to report not only log messages with levels INFO and higher but e.g. for DEBUG and higher:

```
log4j.logger.ros=DEBUG
log4j.logger.ros.roscpp.superdebug=WARN
```

Unfortunately this really spams the log with all the debug messages coming from ROS nodes. How do I configure ROS to use the log level `>=INFO` for ROS' own nodes and `>=DEBUG` for my own nodes?

Also what is the meaning of

```
log4j.logger.ros.roscpp.superdebug
```

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197392/set-log-level-for-non-ros-nodes-(my-own-nodes)/) by [SR](https://answers.ros.org/users/14071/sr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 152 on 2014-11-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just set the logger for you nodes only, but not ros in general, e.g.:

`log4j.logger.ros.trajectory_planner=DEBUG`

`superdebug` is afaik basically a super-spammy debug. Something you'll probably never need, unless you are a core developer or have problems with the middleware/roscpp itself.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SR](https://answers.ros.org/users/14071/sr/) on 2014-11-17**:
Thanks. It works!